# Filtering Json data, no results

Tags: json, powershell

My JSON file `export.json` has this [content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2jaF.jpg).

```json
[
  {
    "Workspace Name": "IAP IPP DW - PRD",
    "Workspace Allowance": "130",
    "Workspace Usage": "108.9413",
    "Workspace Size Free": "21.1",
    "Percentage Utilization": "0.83801",
    "Predicted Usage": "146.9888958"
  },
  {
    "Workspace Name": "Connected planning Facilities-PRD",
    "Workspace Allowance": "130",
    "Workspace Usage": "81.2462",
    "Workspace Size Free": "48.8",
    "Percentage Utilization": "0.624970769",
    "Predicted Usage": "85.79967522"
  },
  {
    "Workspace Name": "Lubes SDA - PROD",
    "Workspace Allowance": "100",
    "Workspace Usage": "78.5773",
    "Workspace Size Free": "21.4",
    "Percentage Utilization": "0.785773",
    "Predicted Usage": "87.03502547"
  },
  {
    "Workspace Name": "IAP IPP DW - ACC",
    "Workspace Allowance": "100",
    "Workspace Usage": "56.272",
    "Workspace Size Free": "43.7",
    "Percentage Utilization": "0.56272",
    "Predicted Usage": "95.58173647"
  },
  {
    "Workspace Name": "ONE Forecast UPD - PRD",
    "Workspace Allowance": "100",
    "Workspace Usage": "42.1855",
    "Workspace Size Free": "57.8",
    "Percentage Utilization": "0.421855",
    "Predicted Usage": "51.76880067"
  },
  {
    "Workspace Name": "IAP IPP DW - DEV",
    "Workspace Allowance": "50",
    "Workspace Usage": "38.7354",
    "Workspace Size Free": "11.3",
    "Percentage Utilization": "0.774708",
    "Predicted Usage": "33.98943696"
  }
]
```

When I write the below code in PowerShell it displays the data set for `Connected planning Facilities-PRD` and `Lubes SDA - PROD` but does not display for `IAP IPP DW - PRD` which should ideally show up because the Workspace Usage for that Model is also 108.

```
$variable =Get-Content "export.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
# Write-Output $variable
$logs=$variable | Where-Object { $_.'Workspace Usage' -ge "75" } 
Write-Output $logs
```

Comment: Use `$_.'Workspace Name'`

Comment: @SiddharthaDas Are you sure? `$variables| Where-Object { $_.'Workspace Name' -eq "IAP IPP DW - PRD" }` shows me the expected item

Comment: Yes it is working as expected now, thanks. But I have edited the question, could you please help there.

Comment: I have posted the answer for your question. Please check below

Comment: In your amended question, use `Where-Object { [double]$_.'Workspace Usage' -ge 75 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function HtmlTable
{
     [OutputType([System.Object])]

    Param (
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String[]]
        $tableRows,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String[]] 
        $tableHeaders,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
        $tableWidthPercentage
    )        
    $htmTable = "<html>
                <style>
                body {font-family:Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana;font-size:12px;}
                table{width: $tableWidthPercentage;border-collapse: collapse;}
                th{background-color:#106ebe; color:white;font-family:Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana;font-size:12px;border: 1px solid black;padding: 4px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid #ddd;}
                tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
                td{font-family:Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana;font-size:12px;border: 1px solid #ddd;padding: 4px;}
                </style>
                <table>
                <tr>"
    Foreach ($header in $tableHeaders)
    {
        $htmTable +=  "<th>$header</th>"
    }
   
    $htmTable +="</tr>
                $tableRows
                </table>"
    return $htmTable
}


$variable =Get-Content -raw "export.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
#$logs=$variable | Where-Object { $_.'Workspace Name' -eq "IAP IPP DW - PRD" -and  $_.'Workspace Usage' -gt 75} 
$logs=$variable | Where-Object { $_.'Workspace Usage' -gt 75 } 

foreach($item in $logs)
{
        
    $WorkspaceName =$item.'Workspace Name'
    $WorkspaceAllowance=$item.'Workspace Allowance'
    $WorkspaceUsage=$item.'Workspace Usage '
    $WorkspaceSizeFree=$item.'Workspace Size Free'
    $PercentageUtilization=$item.'Percentage Utilization'
    $PredictedUsage=$item.'Predicted Usage'
    
    $resultRow = "
                <tr>
                <td>$WorkspaceName</td>
                <td>$WorkspaceAllowance</td>
                <td>$WorkspaceUsage</td>
                <td>$WorkspaceSizeFree</td>
                <td>$PercentageUtilization</td>
                <td>$PredictedUsage</td>
                </tr>
                "
    $table_content += $resultRow
}


$body = HtmlTable -tableWidthPercentage 90% -tableRows $table_content -tableHeaders WorkspaceName,WorkspaceAllowance,WorkspaceUsage,WorkspaceSizeFree,PercentageUtilization,PredictedUsage


Send-MailMessage -From <from address> -To <to address> -Cc <cclist> -SmtpServer <smtp server address> -Subject "testing script" -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
Clear-Variable -Name "logs"
Write-Host "Done Sending Email"



<#
Please update the below details from the PowerShell script
Send-MailMessage -From <from address> -To <to address> -Cc <cclist> -SmtpServer <smtp server address> -Subject "testing script" -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
#>


***PFA for sample output. Also please mark this as answer if you feel this is an answer***
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works perfectly. 
The only concern is the subject line comes as "UnTrusted Message :TEST EMAIL" although I have given only TEST EMAIL as the subject

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable = Get-Content -raw "export.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$logs = $variable | Where-Object { $_.'Workspace Usage' -gt 75 } 

Write-Output $logs
```

Output

```
Workspace Name         : Connected planning Facilities-PRD
Workspace Allowance    : 130
Workspace Usage        : 81.2462
Workspace Size Free    : 48.8
Percentage Utilization : 0.624970769
Predicted Usage        : 85.79967522

Workspace Name         : Lubes SDA - PROD
Workspace Allowance    : 100
Workspace Usage        : 78.5773
Workspace Size Free    : 21.4
Percentage Utilization : 0.785773
Predicted Usage        : 87.03502547
```

Comment: i am not able to filter out only the workspace names with workspace usage greater than equal to 75. I have attached the output screenshot as OUTPUT FILE to my post.

Comment: $variable =Get-Content -raw "export.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$logs=$variable | Where-Object { $_.'Workspace Usage' -gt 75 } 
Write-Output $logs

Comment: It doesn't work either. Workspace usage having 9.81 value is also showing up.

Comment: I have pasted the output to you

Comment: Also I don't see any $_.Workspace Usage value with 9.81 from the above inputs

Comment: In your output workspace usage 81 and 78 is appearing but 108.94 which is the workspace usage for the first dataset is not appearing. that should appear too.

Comment: @AdminOfThings - When i send a mail of the filtered list of workspaces bearing workspace usage -ge 75, i get an output like below in my outlook inbox.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is all of the JSON deserialized values are strings. You are intending to do a numerical comparison and must ensure all data being compared are numeric types.

```
$variable | Where { [double]$_.'Workspace Usage' -ge 75 }
```

**Output:**

```
Workspace Name         : IAP IPP DW - PRD
Workspace Allowance    : 130
Workspace Usage        : 108.9413
Workspace Size Free    : 21.1
Percentage Utilization : 0.83801
Predicted Usage        : 146.9888958

Workspace Name         : Connected planning Facilities-PRD
Workspace Allowance    : 130
Workspace Usage        : 81.2462
Workspace Size Free    : 48.8
Percentage Utilization : 0.624970769
Predicted Usage        : 85.79967522

Workspace Name         : Lubes SDA - PROD
Workspace Allowance    : 100
Workspace Usage        : 78.5773
Workspace Size Free    : 21.4
Percentage Utilization : 0.785773
Predicted Usage        : 87.03502547
```

The left-hand side (LHS) of an operator influences the type of the RHS of the operator ***if a type conversion can be done on the RHS***. Thus, by casting the LHS to `[double]` the number on the RHS (`75`) is converted to `[double]` also. Then the comparison executes as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: When i send the workspaces bearing usage -ge 75, i get a very unformatted mail in my inbox like attached to this post. (MAIL SNIPPET). I want it in a organised format like below
Workspace Name         : Lubes SDA - PROD
Workspace Allowance    : 100
Workspace Usage        : 78.5773
Workspace Size Free    : 21.4
Percentage Utilization : 0.785773
Predicted Usage        : 87.03502547

Comment: I AM USING THIS CODE for sending the mail.

try
{
 Send-MailMessage @smtpsettings -Body $messagebody -BodyAsHtml -Encoding utf8 -verbose -ErrorAction Stop
}

catch
{
    Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
}

Comment: That happens because the body of your email is not a string. It is an array of objects that is being converted to a string for the `-Body` parameter. You need to construct your own string first to your liking. You could do something like `-Body ($messagebody | Out-String)`

Comment: How to update cell A1 of an excel/csv with the value "Workspace Name"